# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: logging, find, python-multithreading

I am trying to test out some multi-threading stuff, but am receiving a lot of clutter around logging. I am getting the error "AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'find'".

Here is my code, followed by a snippet of the error printout:

```
import threading
import time
import logging
import time

def wait_func(time_to_wait,name):
    logging.info(f'{name} waiting..')
    time.sleep(time_to_wait)
    logging.info(f'{name} done waiting')

logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO)
threads = list()
for i in range(3):
    name = 't' + str(i)
    logging.info(f'starting {name}')
    x = threading.Thread(target=wait_func, args=(i*3,name))
    threads.append(x)
    x.start()

for index, thread in enumerate(threads):
    logging.info(f"Main    : before joining thread {index}.")
    thread.join()
    logging.info(f"Main    : thread {index} done")
```

Here is the error text:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/moninghoffjc/anaconda3/envs/psychopyNEW/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 994, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/Users/moninghoffjc/anaconda3/envs/psychopyNEW/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 840, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/Users/moninghoffjc/anaconda3/envs/psychopyNEW/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 578, in format
    if self.usesTime():
  File "/Users/moninghoffjc/anaconda3/envs/psychopyNEW/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 546, in usesTime
    return self._style.usesTime()
  File "/Users/moninghoffjc/anaconda3/envs/psychopyNEW/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 388, in usesTime
    return self._fmt.find(self.asctime_search) >= 0
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'find'
Call stack:
  File "/Users/moninghoffjc/anaconda3/envs/psychopyNEW/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "/Users/moninghoffjc/anaconda3/envs/psychopyNEW/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/moninghoffjc/anaconda3/envs/psychopyNEW/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-18-ae212a132b6e>", line 7, in wait_func
    logging.critical(f'{name} waiting..')
Message: 't0 waiting..'
Arguments: ()
```

It seems like it's not a problem with my code, but I'm not sure what to do to rectify it. The clutter makes my logging.info very obnoxious to read.

Comment: What is `format`?  The problem appears to occur when logging tries to format a message.

Comment: The `format=` keyword argument to `logging.basicConfig` is supposed to a string.  It looks like you are passing the built-in function `format` instead.